# Need help packing an executable .jar in java

Tags: java, jar

Ok, I have this file I use for debugging purposes while I'm writing some code. However, I am looking to speed up the process by packing it in an executable .jar file. I have been creating a jar file via eclipse, and attempting to run it as is.

The contents of the jar (`Derivitave Quiz.jar`) are as follows:

- `DerivQuiz.java`
- `DerivQuiz.class`
- `Meta-INF` (empty folder)
- `pass.txt`

Also, would I have to re-write it to use a non-command line output, such as `Jpane`/`JOptionPane`, instead of `System.out.print()`?

My current code works fine in Eclipse, but not after porting to a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did have to change all my print statements to use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` instead of `System.out.print()`.

Upon further inspection, the jar was being created without a manifest file, not allowing the jar to run.

I fixed this by adding a manifest file under `META-INF/manifest.xml`, with the following code:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_27 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MCExploit
```

Adding this allows the jar to run flawlessly, in addition to the other adjustments I made.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this far too complicated, especially if you're flummoxed by a task as simple as creating a JAR file.

All you need is javac.exe and jar.exe that come with the JDK.  Look at this tutorial to show you how to do it properly:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Comment: yeah, I don't have access to the local hard drive for now, and want this done as soon as I can get it done.

and the computer I'm on doesn't have a JDK installed. just what I have on my flash drives.

Comment: You can't create JAR files without the JDK AFAIK.

Comment: I can make a .jar, that's not hard
but I'm looking for a reason it won't execute. is it due to a coding reason or somethign else?

Comment: It's probably because you didn't create it properly.  Who can tell based on what you've posted?  Not me.

Comment: to create it, I used Jcreator's "create a jar" tool, but it doesn't do anything except open java in the background

Answer (score 1):

Duffymo's answer is good. But let me add something: if you're using Eclipse, you simply go to File -> Export then choose 'Executable Jar', and it does it automatically. Here's a nice guide for doing it a few different ways (including with Eclipse):

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html

Comment: and would I need to re-write it using Jpane or something similar instead of System.out.print statements? or are those compatible with executable jars?

Comment: @azulflame I'm a bit lost at the moment to be honest. Not sure what you're trying to do or what tools you do/don't have at your disposal.

Comment: @azulflame This is what I got from the question: "I have these resources: launch4j (.jar wrapper I'm not used to), eclipse, Jcreator, and netbeans, as well as needed JDK's." I responded accordingly.